# Where to ask a question regarding the capabilities of a specific light intensity sensor?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have an interesting question. Please help me find a site where it would be appropriate.

> - Can I use the BH1750FVI digital light intensity light sensor to measure the wavelength of a sample?
>
> (https://www.instructables.com/BH1750-Digital-Light-Sensor/)
>
> According to my research, I found that the BH1750 light sensor used
> with Arduino can express light intensity in lux units, but I
> want to measure the wavelength of a sample in nanometers.
>
> Can I use this light sensor?

Comment: It sounds like [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) might be a good fit for your question.

Answer (score 4):

It depends, primarily, on what you are fundamentally asking. You seem to be asking:

> Can I use this light sensor to measure the wavelength of a sample in nanometers?

I'm no Arduino expert, but the BH1750FVI sensor can be used with an Arduino (and, from what I can tell, is primarily used with Arduino). So immediately [Arduino.SE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) comes to mind. On Arduino.SE, there are [two questions asking about the BH1750FVI sensor](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/search?q=BH1750FVI+is%3Aq). And there is even a tag for sensors on Arduino.SE, so it would definitely be on-topic.

Aditionally, there seem to be some questions about the BH1750FVI sensor on [Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=BH1750FVI). So that's another option.

It depends on whether the arduino is an essential part of your question. If you are using the BH1750FVI sensor *with the arduino*, then Arduino.SE is the best choice. If the arduino is not an essential part of your question, then go with Electronics.SE.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm just starting to use this website. It is quite new for me.